# How do I create a svn Repository and then use XCode 4 with it?

Tags: xcode

I would like to create an svn repository in a local folder on my MacBook Pro running Lion 10.7. 
I would then like to use Xcode 4 tools to interface with it.  I'm stuggling to find a step by step tutorial on how to do this.  Can someone please point me in the right direction as far as documentation or tutorials to do this.  Thanks very much in advance to anyone that can help.

Kind Regards,
Don.

Answer (score 1):

SVN is a centralized versionning tool, you'll need a server to run the main repo.

If you're not running one in local, use a decentralized one instead, like git which is also supportes by Xcode